# Unexpected beginning of statement

Tags: mysql

Hi I just followed a YouTube video and created this but it won't let me create the tables how do I fix it?

*2 errors were found during analysis .
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "member_id" at position 24)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "SMALLINT" at position 34)*

[image]

```
CREATE TABLES members(
member_id SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
name VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
phone CHAR(10) NOT NALL DEFAULT'000000000',
membership_status ENUM('gold','silver,''bronze','nam') NOT NULL DEFAULT'nam',
PRIMARY KEY (member_id)
)
```

Comment: One of multiple issues probably: "NOT NALL" and a missing single quote after silver

Answer (score 2):

You had multiple typos (missing single quote, you wrote NAL instead of NULL). This query will work:

```
CREATE TABLE `members` (
  `member_id` SMALLINT(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
  `phone` CHAR(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '000000000',
  `membership_status` ENUM('gold', 'silver', 'bronze', 'nam') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'nam',
  PRIMARY KEY (`member_id`));
```

Furthermore you may want to look into different tutorials. In my oppinion no one should use ENUMs anymore, because of several disadvantages. Maybe someone can write a good tutorial tip here. Maybe this is something for you: https://www.codecademy.com/learn/learn-sql

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLES members(
member_id SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
name VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
phone CHAR(10) NOT NALL DEFAULT'000000000',
membership_status ENUM('gold','silver,''bronze','nam') NOT NULL DEFAULT'nam',
PRIMARY KEY (member_id)
);
```

Try by doing this. As it seems, there is no `;` mark in the closing.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `create tables` to `create table`.

Comment: Please update the question to reflect the latest changes and output.